# Removing a specific li

Tags: jquery

```
<li class="checkinUserPhotoImageContainer" id="">
  <img src="<%=checkin_image['image_url']%>"/>

    <span class="delChkPhotoImgOut">
           <span class="delChkPhotoImg"></span>
   </span>

</li>

<li class="checkinUserPhotoImageContainer" id="">
  <img src="<%=checkin_image['image_url']%>"/>

    <span class="delChkPhotoImgOut">
           <span class="delChkPhotoImg"></span>
   </span>

</li>
<li class="checkinUserPhotoImageContainer" id="">
  <img src="<%=checkin_image['image_url']%>"/>

    <span class="delChkPhotoImgOut">
           <span class="delChkPhotoImg"></span>
   </span>

</li>
<li class="checkinUserPhotoImageContainer" id="">
  <img src="<%=checkin_image['image_url']%>"/>

    <span class="delChkPhotoImgOut">
           <span class="delChkPhotoImg"></span>
   </span>

</li>
```

Now the span having class delChkPhotoImgOut is a delete button applied using css, I want when a user click on that button its parent li is removed from the UL list.Please Help me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the parent/ancestor `<li>` then [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it, like this:

```
$(".delChkPhotoImg").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

To be more specific you can use `.closest(".checkinUserPhotoImageContainer")` as well. A better/cheaper approach would be to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) here on the parent `<ul>`, like this:

```
$("#listID").delegate(".delChkPhotoImg", "click", function() {
  $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```